# How to copy a R list object to Excel using the writeClipboard function while preserving the structure and all the names in the original list object?

Tags: r, excel, list

I am using the line of code `writeClipboard(gsub(" +", "\t", capture.output(print(nested_list, max = 1e6))))` to copy/paste list object `nested_list` to Excel. The code works fine when there are no whitespaces in the embedded matrix column names, but erroneously adds columns when pasting if there are whitespaces in embedded matrix column names. I show correct R studio output on the left in the image below, the incorrect output when copying/pasting to Excel using the above line of code in the middle of the image below, and the desired output in Excel on the right side of the image below. I would best case like to preserve the whitespaces in the original matrix column names, and second best case replace those whitespaces with underscores "_". Any suggestions for how to do this?

Code for generating `nested_list` is at the bottom of this post.

[image]

Code:

```
nested_list <- list(
  A = list(
    B = list(
      C = matrix(1:6,2,3, dimnames = list(NULL,c("Big Bob","Fat Tom","Old Rob"))),
      D = matrix(7:8,2,1, dimnames = list(NULL,"Ink"))
    ),
    E = matrix(9:16,2,4, dimnames = list(NULL,c("Dog","Fat Cat","Rat","Bat")))
  ),
  F = list(
    G = matrix(17:22,2,3, dimnames = list(NULL,c("Sue","Peg","Jen"))),
    H = matrix(23:28,2,3, dimnames = list(NULL,c("AAA","BBB","CCC")))
  ),
  I = matrix(1:4,2,2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("Big Fat","Pig")))
)
```

Comment: This strikes me as a question we need to take a step back from and ask "why?" on. Why do we need to write a nested list to the clipboard like this, why not just write each matrix directly to `.csv/.xlsx`? The reason your solution doesn't work is that when you dump it to text first, there's no way to differentiate a space in a column name vs. a space between columns. If you start by replacing all the spaces with `_`, i.e. `Big_Bob` it would probably work, but again I struggle to see why this would be the optimal solution.

Comment: Because of speed: I need to double check calculations and XLS is easy for that, with a quick copy/paste into XLS from R. I also need to maintain the list structure and names intact to check for logic, uniqueness, etc. because the list is read by Shiny and other packages for generating table extracts. The logic used in the list names is important for the other functions that read the list. R packages like writexl require that the list be converted to dataframe, destroying the list/nesting structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

1. Replace spaces in column / rownames (and potentially values in case your nested values will contain text with spaces) first by a character which is guaranteed not to  appear in names / values
2. Replace spaces in `capture.output` by tabs
3. Replace the mask character back to spaces.

*N.B.* I ammended the examples list by a acharcter matrix to show why values should be considered as well.

`rapply` helps you with the nested structure,

```r
nested_list <- list(
  A = list(
    B = list(
      C = matrix(1:6,2,3, dimnames = list(NULL,c("Big Bob","Fat Tom","Old Rob"))),
      D = matrix(7:8,2,1, dimnames = list(NULL,"Ink"))
    ),
    E = matrix(9:16,2,4, dimnames = list(NULL,c("Dog","Fat Cat","Rat","Bat")))
  ),
  F = list(
    G = matrix(17:22,2,3, dimnames = list(NULL,c("Sue","Peg","Jen"))),
    H = matrix(23:28,2,3, dimnames = list(NULL,c("AAA","BBB","CCC")))
  ),
  I = matrix(1:4,2,2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("Big Fat","Pig"))),
  J = matrix(c("a a", "b b"), 2, 1)
)

mask_names <- function(m, mask = "_") {
  if (length(colnames(m)))
    colnames(m) <- gsub("\\s", mask, colnames(m))
  if (length(rownames(m)))
    rownames(m) <- gsub("\\s", mask, rownames(m))
  m[] <- gsub("\\s", mask, m)
  m
}

mask <- "_"
stopifnot(!grepl(mask, rapply(nested_list, \(x) c(colnames(x), rownames(x), x))))

writeClipboard(
  gsub(mask, " ",
       gsub("\\s+", "\t", 
            capture.output(
              print(
                rapply(nested_list, mask_names,how = "replace", mask = mask)
              )
            )
       )
  )
)
```

To make it even more bullet proof, you would need to apply the same logic to the names of the nested lists themselves (think of `nested_list <- c(nested_list, "non syntactic name" = matrix(1:4, 2, 2)`), but may not be necessary if you have control over the slot names / don't care oin the Excel about mis placed list names.